# Regex to not match a pattern in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a reqular expression to not match this `(/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)` pattern, where the string needs to start with alphabet followed by number and alphabet, with no special characters.

I tried with `(/^?![a-zA-Z]?![a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)` and not able to get appropriate answer.

Example:

```
P123454(Invalid)
PP1234(Invalid)
1245P(valid)
@#$124(valid)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: like this? `/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$/`

Comment: Please, provide examples of the matched cases.

Comment: @Mina edited. please check

Comment: btw: I use https://www.regexpal.com to quickly debug my regexs.

Comment: Is `P123454P` valid?

Comment: @The fourth bird - My question was to not match the valid regex which I have provided.I have edited my question. 'P123454P' is valid hence it shouldn't match the pattern

Answer (score 0):

This regex might be helpful:

```
/^[^a-zA-Z]+.*$/g
```

Your every valid input (from the question) should be a match.

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OE6wVP/1)

Explanation:

- Does not allow string starting with `a-zA-Z`
- Everything after than is allowed (I'm not sure if this is a requirement)

Comment: My question was to not match valid regex, updated question, please check

Comment: Please post your question with a good review. I've updated the regex. Please see if it fits your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`^` means start with, So it should start with an alphabetic letter, then any number `\d` of alphabetic letters `a-z` with `i` case insensitive flag.

```js
const check = (str) => {
   return /^[^a-z].*/i.test(str)
}


console.log(check('P123454'))
console.log(check('PP1234'))
console.log(check('1245P'))
console.log(check('@#$124'))
```

Comment: My question was to not match valid regex, updated question, please check

Comment: Updated, please check again.

Comment: P!123P This is failing, no special character allowed

Comment: Yes, you said that you don't want the first character to be a letter.

Comment: "the string needs to start with alphabet followed by number and alphabet, with no special characters". as part of question

Comment: That's what I did, and you said I want to reverse that.